# What Component of Audio Music Visualizers Use

Tags: audio, signals, signal-processing

If you were to take, for example, Trap Nation's music visualizer ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBltcktWq_8)) and looked at just the "intensity" they use to control the undulation of the circle, how is that calculated. I tried writing my own version and I simply was using the waveform with a little bit of smoothing and filtering, but I still got very large amounts of added noise in my data (noise which you can't hear at all). For example, I made a little sample audio file by just using Garage Band and the clarinet instrument. I noticed that my visualizer (as well Audacity) would show the volume increasing and decreasing at a rapid rate even when nothing was playing. I am getting my terms mixed up? **Do these types of music visualizers simply use the waveform with more filtering, or do they use some completely different measure.**[image: Example]

This is an example of what I mean. This is the test file I created and the volume over the past ~0.8 seconds and continuing for the next ~0.2 seconds decreased like a decaying `sin` wave.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?? And What does this have to do with Java??? Unless you are affixing some snipeds: remove Java fron the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms of Fourier transforms (DFT/FFT/STFT/DCT) are commonly used software transformations of audio for visualization, but so are others, such as wavelet decompositions, cepstrums, MFCCs, autocorrelations, & etc.